# Game Center - Combined Leaderboard?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I'm not totally clear on how a combined leaderboard works.

for example lets say i have a racing game and i want to combine the leaderboards for 3 levels..  if one player finishes all three with a time of 30 seconds on each one, and the other player finishes only one race with a time of 10 seconds who appears first on the combined leaderboard?

How does it work when youre combining scores for players who have not scored on the other leaderboards?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if someone doesn't have scores in all three leaderboards that it just shows "Not ranked". If however, they have 10 seconds in all three leaderboards, then if faster is better, that person would be higher ranked than the first person.